# Line overflow when using biblatex citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, line-breaking, authoryear, overfull

### Background

I have defined a set of citations in the following style in a .bib file.

```
    @inproceedings{McKinney.2010,
        author = {{Mc\-Kinney}, Wes},
        title = {Data Structures for Statistical Computing in Python},
        pages = {56--61},
        publisher = {SciPy},
        series = {Proceedings of the Python in Science Conference},
        booktitle = {Proceedings of the 9th Python in Science Conference},
        year = {2010},
        doi = {10.25080/Majora-92bf1922-00a},
        file = {McKinney 2010 - Data Structures for Statistical Computing:Attachments/McKinney 2010 - Data Structures for Statistical Computing.pdf:application/pdf}
    }
```

Now I try to reference the article in my text using biblatex with the following settings

```
\RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

as following:

```latex
This is my example text in which I try to use a citation (\cite{McKinney.2010}).
```

### Problem

After rendering ( meaning in the pdf viewer ) the citation (McKinney.2010) is ending
further right than the rest of the block text.

---

[image: First line of text is ending is ending further right than the rest of the text, represented by the bottom line.]

---

I want to ( preferably automatic ) insert an appropriate linebreak into the citation so that it does not show overhang.

### Setup

**Full Package List:**

```latex
    \RequirePackage{caption}
    \RequirePackage{subcaption}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{lmodern}
    \RequirePackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
    \RequirePackage{amsfonts}
    \RequirePackage{amsmath}
    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \RequirePackage{amssymb}
    \RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \RequirePackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
    \RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \RequirePackage{expdlist}
    \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \RequirePackage{longtable}
    \RequirePackage{MnSymbol}
    \RequirePackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \RequirePackage{titling}
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
    \RequirePackage{rotating}
    \RequirePackage{pdflscape}
    \RequirePackage{lipsum}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \RequirePackage[german]{varioref}
    \RequirePackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,textwidth=15cm,textheight=22.7cm]{geometry}
    \RequirePackage{url}
    \RequirePackage{multicol}
    \RequirePackage{enumitem}
    \RequirePackage[automake,acronym,toc,section]{glossaries}
    \RequirePackage{booktabs}
    \RequirePackage{listings}
    \RequirePackage{tabu}
    \RequirePackage{mdframed}
    \RequirePackage{ntheorem}
    \RequirePackage{xurl}
    \RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
```

**Document Setup**

```latex
    \documentclass[a4paper,
    oneside,
    openany,
    11pt,
    bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
    \addbibresource{Quellen/literatur.bib}
```

Comment: **bold** citation keys mean that `biblatex` did not actually manage to resolve your citations at all. There should be loads of warnings about this. Your citations should come out very differently if everything worked properly. It's hard to say what exactly is going wrong in your document since you have not shown a complete example document and not shown any log messages. ...

Comment: ... But the most likely explanation is that you did not actually run Biber on your document. Your document needs to be compiled with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber does. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can get your editor to run Biber for you. Make sure to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, then look at the `.log` and `.blg` files and search for errors/warnings.

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much! Running Biber solved the issue.